# How do I get new filesystem formats to use in mkfs?

Tags: filesystems, rhel

I am currently attempting to run some benchmark tests using different filesystem formats. However, I can only use the ext family, cramfs, and msdos formats with mkfs since those are the only formats available on my machine.

How can I get different filesystem formats configured on my machine such that I can run mkfs and specify this new type (i.e., mkfs -t btrfs ...and so on).

I am running Red Hat Enterprise if that matters.

UPDATE:
I guess I should clarify, I am attempting to use filesystem formats which are currently not recognized by my machine. In the example used above, I cannot make use of btrfs because my machine has not been configured to recognize btrfs much less have mkfs be capable to creating a filesystem using that format.

Comment: For RHEL 7, see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/index.html

Comment: Also, you could compile your own kernel to add support for any that RH declined to; https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/